# How to combine a set of features and report their effectiveness with only one number?

Tags: feature-selection

I have a binary classification problem. My data set has 100 features with 10 different categories (10 features per category). I want to report the effectiveness (in terms of classification) with a single number. 
The first thing which comes in mind is correlating all the features with the class label and sum up the absolute value of the results in each category.
I am wondering if there is a better way of combining the features?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell if this is what you'd want, since you haven't given much context, but how about fitting your classifier with only one category of features at a time, and then using the classifier's accuracy as your measure of how useful the features in that category are?

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a good approach. But it is classifier-dependent. It means that it depends on what classifier/algorithm we use. I am wondering if there is a technique using only values of features and class labels.

Comment: But the thing you want to measure (namely, the usefulness of features for classification) is also classifier-dependent. So long as you measure classification performance at all, you're implicitly using *some* classifier. But, you can certainly try several different classifiers and find the best accuracy, in case different classifiers work better for different categories of features.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for feature filters and feature wrappers.

**Feature filters** look at the features and target variable *without incorporating a model*. So they typically do something like selecting features to minimize inter-feature correlation and maximize feature-target-variable correlation. This is similar to what you mentioned in your question if I got that correctly. The advantage with filters is they being relatively fast, as they don't do model training/evaluation. The drawback is that they don't incorporate a model, hence don't look at your actual model performance that results from those features at all. They therefore don't necessarily improve your final performance (similar to e.g. PCA, which might improve or reduce your model performance, depending on which data you use it at).

**Feature wrappers** additionally *incorporate a model* in the process, so they essentially train and evaluate a model with a subset of your features. There exist e.g. forward- and backward-selection-wrappers, and hybrids of those (they either start with 0 features and add features to improve performance, or start with all features and remove features to improve performance, or do a mix of both).

BTW: depending on which software you use, these are likely already pre-implemented (e.g. for R caret, see http://topepo.github.io/caret/featureselection.html)